# Metro Bundler not working, what can I do?

Tags: react-native, metro-bundler

[raw code//Appearing the content of the app.json file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/np00m.png)
raw code//Appearing the content of the app.json file

Answer (score 0):

Metro Bundler UI is no longer available after **expo-cli@6.0.0**.

> Update July 25, 2022: expo-cli@6.0.0 has been released with the web UI removed. The last release to include the web UI is expo-cli@5.5.1.

https://blog.expo.dev/sunsetting-the-web-ui-for-expo-cli-ab12936d2206?gi=4f34076db816